# textbox to accept only one character at a time

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I need to make a `TextBox` control accept only one character at a time. For instance if I input *"aaa"*, then it would only accept *"a"*.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can only write one character at a time. Do you mean repeated characters?

Comment: You want that the length of Text property would not more than 1, yes?

Comment: `if I send "aaa"` How do you send all of them at a time?

Answer (score 2):

TextBox has a `MaxLength` property. `MaxLength` gets or sets the maximum number of characters that can be manually entered into the text box.

```
 <TextBox MaxLength="1" Width="120" Height="23" />
```

So here, you can enter only one character manually.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the user to be able to enter the same key more than once in a row. This should prevent that:

```
 private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
     if(textBox != null)
     {
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
         {
             //get the last character and convert it to a key
             char prevChar = textBox.Text[textBox.Text.Length - 1];
             Keys k = (Keys)char.ToUpper(prevChar);

             //compare the Key pressed to the previous Key
             if (e.KeyData == k)
             {
                 //suppress the keypress if the key is the same as the previous one
                 e.SuppressKeyPress = true;              
             }
         }
     }
 }
```